# Airflow schedule once but doesn't start

Tags: python, airflow

I scheduled an Airflow dag like below. What I expect to see is the dag runs once with execution date 2023-08-01. However nothing happens and no dag runs were created. How can I schedule a job to be run once on a specific date?

```
start_date: '2023-08-01T00:00:00'
catchup: True
schedule_interval: 'Once'
```

Comment: If it is a small task and is in python you can use pythons packages like pyScheduler for the same.

Comment: Thanks but pyScheduler is not an option for me at the moment.